# Rails associated field verify typed in value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that currently uses the following in a Workorder form to select a Parent Workorder:

```
<%= f.association :parent, :collection => Workorder.wonotclosed(:order => :wonum), :label_method => :wonum, :label => 'Parent WO' %>
```

This is in the workorder.rb:

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Workorder", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
```

The problem is that the database now has thousands of Workorders and the dropdown is causing timeouts.  Plus it's not very user friendly.

Using the association verifies that the user enters a Workorder that is already in the system.

If I change the field to a text entry - for instance Wonum = 14-36666

how could I verify they entered a Wonum that is in the table?

Thanks for the help!!!

UDPATE1

Not every Workorder will have a parent. Another issue is that `ID` is the key and the associated field is `parent_id`.  But, I need the user to type in `wonum`.

This might help, except with the issue of typing in `wonum`:

```
validates_associated :parent
```

Comment: This may help http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?view=asciicast

Comment: sp1rs thanks!  That's a very useful idea and I'm sure I will use it in the future.  But, I think it's a bad fit for this situation.  I would prefer that the form came back similar to `validates_presence_of`. I envision it saying "workorder not found".